# TM4C123 SPI slave reads only one byte

Tags: microcontroller, spi, texas-instruments, tm4c123g

I'm sending the following sequence to an SPI slave in a Tiva TM4C123GXL board:

[image]

I have captured this directly from the MCU pins. Notice SCK is running at ~190 kHz (pretty slow).

The problem is that my SPI slave reads only the first byte. The code is below:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"

#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/uart.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/ssi.h"

#include "utils/uartstdio.h"


static void SPISlaveInit(void)
{
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_SSI1);

    SSIConfigSetExpClk(
        SSI1_BASE,
        SysCtlClockGet(),
        SSI_FRF_MOTO_MODE_0,
        SSI_MODE_SLAVE,
        1000000,
        8
    );

    SSIEnable(SSI1_BASE);

    uint32_t rd = 0;
    while(SSIDataGetNonBlocking(SSI1_BASE, &rd)) {
        // NOP
    }
}

static void UARTInit(void)
{
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_UART0);
    UARTStdioConfig(0, 115200, SysCtlClockGet());
}

/**
 * @brief Init. the required GPIOs.
 *
 */
static void GPIOInit(void)
{
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOD);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);

    // Config. PF2 and 3 as outputs to use the LED.
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);

    // Config. PA2 as input to use it as button. PF0 and 4
    // (user buttons) don't work.
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
    GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPD);
}

/**
 * @brief Init. GPIOs alternate functions.
 *
 */
static void GPIOPinMux(void)
{
    // UART
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA0_U0RX);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA1_U0TX);
    GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1);

    // SPI slave
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PD0_SSI1CLK);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PD1_SSI1FSS);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PD2_SSI1RX);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PD3_SSI1TX);
    GPIOPinTypeSSI(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3);
}

int main(void)
{
    GPIOInit();
    GPIOPinMux();
    SPISlaveInit();
    UARTInit();

    uint32_t led_val = GPIO_PIN_3;

    GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, led_val);

    uint32_t rd = 20;
    while (true) {
        SSIDataGet(SSI1_BASE, &rd);
        
        UARTprintf("%x\r\n", rd); // This can cause slowness, but the SPI FIFO is 8 half-words deep.

        led_val = led_val == 0 ? GPIO_PIN_3 : 0;
        
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, led_val);
    }
}
```

The output I obtain is `0x54` (the first byte sent) but nothing else.

The board is wired so that:

- MOSI goes to PD2 (SSI1RX)
- MISO goes to PD3 (SSI1TX)
- SCK goes to PD0 (SSI1CLK)
- SS goes to PD1 (SSI1FSS)

The MCU core clock is running at 16MHz, same as the SPI peripheral as you can see in the initialization. The MCU should have time more than enough to read all this data.

I don't understand what is going wrong.

### EDIT

I have confirmed that `SSIDataGet` blocks for ever when trying to read for the second time.

Also, as requested in the comments, I have taken some captures with my oscilloscope:

**SCK and SS signals**

[image]

**SCK and MOSI signals**

[image]

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope rather than a logic analyzer? It might reveal something "analog" going on with your signals. Also a schematic might help.

Comment: What is your "SPI slave" and how sure you are that your sequence fits the protocol of you SPI slave?

Comment: @Ale..chenski My SPI slave is the TM4C123 board I mentioned above. The slave is what I'm trying to program